# Redux as model repository

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm thinking about using redux as a hard repository for our backend models.

e.g.

```
endpoints:
/cars
/cars/:id

actions:
 listCars
 createCar
 getCar
 deleteCar
 updateCar
```

however i'm not sure how to implement relations properly. Lets say for example calling the api /car/1 gives me the following and i'm maintaining the same structure for tires as i do in the car example given above.

```
{
 id:123,
 tires:[41,54,12,10]
}
```

in this case i would love to eager load the tire id's and map them inside the car reducer. Currently i have a wrapper method which maps data cross reducers but it isn't the prettiest solution. I realise i can also map state in container components but considering there's multiple containers i would like to prevent code replication and work from a single source of truth (redux)

I was wondering if there's a common pattern i could follow for this implementation and if this is a good idea altogether

Comment: Please see my answer. If I misunderstood your question or need to clarify something please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your state is:

```
cars: {
    123: {
        id: 123,
        tires: [41,54,12,10]
    }   
},
tires: {
    41: {
        id: 41,
        brand: //...
    },
    54: {
        id: 54,
        brand: //...
    },

    // ...
}
```

Selectors would be:

```
const getTireIds = (state, { carId }) => state.cars[carId].tires;
const getTire = (state, { id }) => state.tires[id];
```

Components would look like:

```
const Car = ({ id }) => <Tires carId={id} />;

const Tires = connect(
    // map state to props:
    (state, { carId }) => ({
        tireIds: getTireIds(state, { carId })
    })
)(
    // component:
    ({ tireIds }) => tireIds.map(tireId => <Tire id={tireId}) />)
);

const Tire = connect(
    // map state to props:
    (state, { id }) => ({
        tire: getTire(state, { id })
    })
)(
    // component:
    ({ tire: { id, brand } }) => // ...
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for.

Comment: Also, this takes for granted the state is already populated with data. I am also looking for a way to dispatch http requests to retrieve the corresponding objects and add these to the state. So lets say, dispatch an action on retrieving tires to retrieve tire data. Or would this responsibility rest with the component?

Comment: The component would dispatch the fetch action. You would also need a way to implement asynchronous actions https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions

Answer (score 0):

https://vuex-orm.org serves well to implement repository pattern out of box. It's been inspired by https://github.com/redux-orm/redux-orm, yet the latter is way less actively maintained.

Vuexorm is litterally the one package i miss most from vue world when working on react project.